# Sealed pipe coming out from back of house - can I cut out safely?

Tags: plumbing

I have a 3 1/2 inch pipe coming out from the back of my house.  It is sealed as you can see from the pictures.  It is very rusted.  Can I cut it near to the ground and reseal it?  What should I watch out for?  How should I reseal it?

[image: Rusted pipe from angle 1]

[image: Rusted pipe from angle 2]

[image: Sealed top of pipe]

[image: Bottom of pipe]

Comment: Very impressive amount of rust activity on that heavy wall thickness pipe.

Comment: I do not see a seal other than debris in a rusted out pipe. If this is what you are asking about the depth below ground dictates what needs to be done. Since it looks to be totally non functional I would cut it off and plug it. Ok how to plug it depends on local conditions.

Comment: That may be a cast iron pipe connected to the sewer. If you cut it, be sure to have on hand a cap for it. Measure the OD carefully and get a rubber cap with fastens with a ss band clamp.

Comment: What might it line up with?  It could be an old sewer vent. Or an old post holding something up that's now gone.

Comment: With all those holes I don’t think it’s sealed any more. It looks like just a pipe stuck in the ground. You could probably just dig it up. I have a hard time believing it is part of a sewer system but I can’t see it in context.

Comment: I recommend digging down to find out if and or what it is connected to.

Comment: it is in the back of the house close to a laundry room, in the corner where there is a sewage pipe - so I am not surprised it would be connected to a sewage pipe.  The house is from the 1920s.